# SCM Information is blank in Manifest.MF created by Jenkins CI builds

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a jenkins build that creates a deployable jar of a multi-module project. Everything is working fine, however the Manifest file within the created jar has the following properties:

```
SCM-Revision: 
SCM-Branch: UNKNOWN_BRANCH
```

This works fine when I run the same project build locally - I get these fields populated as expected:

```
SCM-Revision: 28946
SCM-Branch: trunk
```

My maven-assembly-plugin is as so:

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <id>package-jar-with-dependencies</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                 <finalName>${project.name}_${jenkins.build.number}</finalName>
                 <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                 </descriptorRefs>
                 <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                       <Specification-Title>${project.name}</Specification-Title>
                       <Specification-Version>${project.version}</Specification-Version>
                       <Implementation-Version>${jenkins.build.number}</Implementation-Version>
                       <SCM-Revision>${buildNumber}</SCM-Revision>
                       <SCM-Branch>${scmBranch}</SCM-Branch>
                    </manifestEntries>
                 </archive>
                 <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                 <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
              </configuration>
           </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Jenkins version is 2.177

Maven version is 3.6.1

Maven assembly version is 3.1.1

Project Java version is 1.8

SVN version is 1.7.14 (<- difference here between my local which is 1.9.9)

Answer (score 0):

Added [this plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html) to the build to use a injected svnkit version rather than the system's svn implementation

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <phase>validate</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>create</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
           <doCheck>false</doCheck>
           <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
           <revisionOnScmFailure>unavailable</revisionOnScmFailure>
           <providerImplementations>
              <svn>javasvn</svn>
           </providerImplementations>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
           <dependency>
              <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
              <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
              <version>1.8.9</version>
           </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</plugin>
```